# Laravel API route conflict with web root

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, routes

In one of my website in laravel, when I tried to integrate angularjs4 everything works fine. But I am facing a conflict issue with api routes and route defined in web

The code in my `web.php` is as follows

```
Route::get('/{path?}', function () {
    return view('site');
})->where('path', '.*')
  ->name('siteapp');
```

Since the above code route everything to the view "site", I cannot able to add api request routes in api.php, example is given below

The link www.mysite.com/api/user routes to the route in "web.php" which should be from api.php

Route in my `api.php`

```
Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
    return ['name' => 'demo'];
})->middleware('jwt.auth');
```

Is there any regular expression to skip the path begin with `www.mysite.com/api/something`

I.e. from `web.php`. Is there any rule to skip path? begin with api in this line "where('path', '.*')"?

As a brief is it possible to skip path begin with api in the rule where('path', '[api]! [---allow all other string-]')

Please adivice

Comment: Try this`->where('path', '^(?!api).*$');` !!

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly what I need

Comment: I posted an answer to help poeple find it most don't read comments :p

Comment: please accept it without upvoting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regEx for that like this :

```
Route::get('/{path?}', function () {
    return view('site');
})->where('path', '^(?!api).*$')
  ->name('siteapp');
```